# App is restarting my phone - Android

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile

An app is randomly restarting my phone. The app is made by me and some friends, and it does not have any problems and big bugs whatsoever. But once every a couple of hours, it restarts my phone. This problem occurs only on Galaxy S4 and S5 as far as i know. On other phones i did not encounter this issue. If i were to guess, i would say that it may be because the phone can't handle it anymore, and it just shuts down for safety reasons but i don't know. The app requires wi-fi, it extracts data from the server often and has basic features, like push messages and notifications . What could be the problem, and why would my phone react in such way? And how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues before, and ended up using [Test Fairy](https://testfairy.com) to deploy to problem devices and get actual logs. Turned out I had a few bugs in my application that caused this behaviour.  TestFairy gives you quite good logs and statistics even on the free tier.

You could also attach the device to your development machine and look at the system logs, there should be something that tells you why this happened.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue in nexus 4, there is only option reinstall OS or try to reset your device.i hope it will work.

Comment: the problem is not with my device. it is with my app :D If i uninstall it, the phone has no problem, but my goal here is to fix the app, so nobody would have to experience it when using the android app